# Error: Error: ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-hdwallet-provider

Error: Error: ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.run (C:\Users\WINDOWS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:92:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
Truffle v5.0.33 (core: 5.0.33)
Node v11.12.0
PS D:\Blockchain Dev\t2>

```
***** Token.sol *****

pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;
contract Token {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        return true;
    }
}


***** Shop.sol *****

pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

import "./Token.sol";

contract Shop {
    struct Product {
        string name;
        string imgPath;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 quantity;
        address seller;
    }
    event AddedProduct(uint256 pid, address seller, uint256 timestamp);
    event BuyProduct(uint256 pid, address buyer, uint256 timestamp);
    mapping (uint256 => Product) products;
    mapping (uint256 => address[]) buying;
    Token token;

    constructor (address _tokenAddress) public {
        token = Token(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function addProduct(
        uint256 _pid,
        string memory _name,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _quantity,
        string memory _imgPath,
        uint256 timestamp
    ) public {
        products[_pid] = Product({
            name: _name,
            imgPath: _imgPath,
            price: _price,
            quantity: _quantity,
            seller: msg.sender
        });
        emit AddedProduct(_pid, msg.sender, timestamp);
    }

    function getProduct(uint256 _pid) public view returns (string memory, uint256, uint256, string memory, address) {
        Product memory product = products[_pid];
        return (product.name, product.price, product.quantity, product.imgPath, product.seller);
    }

    function buyProduct(uint256 _pid, uint256 _timestamp) public {
        require(products[_pid].quantity > 0, "Product is sold out");

        Product storage product = products[_pid];
        address _buyer = msg.sender;
        token.transfer(_buyer, product.seller, product.price);

        product.quantity -= 1;

        buying[_pid].push(_buyer);
        emit BuyProduct(_pid, _buyer, _timestamp);
    }
}


***** 2_deploy_contracts.js *****

const Token = artifacts.require('./Token.sol');
const Shop = artifacts.require('./Shop.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer, network , accounts) {
  deployer
    .deploy(Token, 1000000)
    .then(async () => {
      const tokenContract = await Token.deployed();
      return deployer.deploy(Shop, tokenContract.address);
    })
    .then(async () => {
      const token = await Token.deployed();
      const coinbase = accounts[0];
      const value = 50000;
      await token.transfer(coinbase, accounts[1], value);
    });
};


***** truffle-config.js *****

const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const mnemonic = ".....";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },

    kovan: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/.....")
      },
      network_id: 42
    },
},

}
```

Comment: please show your smart contract code, high chance the reason it revert because you call revert function

Comment: @haxerl I've added the code

Comment: can you show also show us at what process did you receive this? When running test? Or when you migrate? or when you run a command

Comment: try to add string in every require function to determine which require revert your function

Comment: @haxerl  truffle migrate --network kovan

Comment: @haxerl I can deploy to a private network but I can not deploy to a public network.

Comment: @haxerl I need a Deploy to the kovan test network. please help me.

Comment: i can't not say for sure what is the cause can u show me your truffle migrate file?

Comment: @haxerl Is already in the body, filename 2_deploy_contracts.js.
Is this file correct?

Comment: Add in your require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value); some word so in case it revert you know the problem is that problem, do this for require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); too i think the revert is trigger by 1 of those but i don't know yet

Comment: That's ok, thank you very much.